# Unable able to communicate between two services

Tags: asp.net, docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have created two `Web API` in `Asp.net Core` one is Wrapper Service to be deployed on DMZ Server and other is core service which have access to our DB Non DMZ. The problem i am facing is that i am unable to communicate between two services.

Both are running on local machine through dockers. When i try to hit core service running on url: `https://localhost:56788/Rewards` thorugh `HttpClient/WebRequest` i got message

`No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.`

**DMZ Controller Logic**

```
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class RewardsController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
        string response = string.Empty;
        //using (var client = new HttpClient())
        //{
        //    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5000/");
        //    //HTTP GET
        //    var responseTask = client.GetAsync("Rewards");
        //    responseTask.Wait();

        //    var result = responseTask.Result;
        //    if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        //    {
        //        response = result.ToString();
        //    }
        //    else //web api sent error response 
        //    {
        //        //log response status here..
        //        response = "Error";
        //    }
        //}
        string sURL = "https://localhost:56788/Rewards";

        WebRequest wrPostURL = WebRequest.Create(sURL);

        wrPostURL.Method = "GET";
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=     (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

        using (HttpWebResponse webresponse = wrPostURL.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
            StreamReader loResponseStream = new StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream(), enc);
            var jsonResponse = loResponseStream.ReadToEnd();
            loResponseStream.Close();
            webresponse.Close();
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

**NON-DMZ Controller Logic**

```
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class RewardsController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

**Update**
This problem is due to dockers. When i deploy both APIs to IIS then it will work fine but i have to do it with Dockers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs due to the fact that i was calling `localhost` to communicate with other `API` running on another container. When we call localhost the first container start looking for the service that is running on same container. By using `VM/Local Machine IP` instead of localhost the problem can be avoided.